# Why in Rails sometimes I need to require a package, and sometimes I don't?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I would like to know yhy in Rails sometimes I need to require a package, and sometimes I don't? Example:

```rb
class Visitor < ApplicationRecord
  validates :ipv4, allow_nil: true, format: { with: Resolv::IPv4::Regex, message: 'is an invalid IPv4' }
end
```

If I don't add `require 'resolv'` in the top of the file, I will have problems when calling the route that calls the controller that is using this model. The error will be:

```
#<NameError: uninitialized constant #<Class:0x0000555f53c743d8>::Resolv>
```

It seems totally arbitrary, although I now there must be some rule that of course I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's all about `autoload` in Rails. By default you need to require the lib, but some gems put autoload to Rails so you don't need to require it when using.

https://www.rubyguides.com/2019/08/autoloading-in-ruby/

Comment: There's also [Bundler](https://bundler.io) which will kick in and auto-load any gems specified in the `Gemfile`, though in this case `Resolv` is packaged with Ruby.